# How many arrangements of banana

Tags: combinatorics

How many arrangements of banana such that the "b" occurs before any of the "a's"?

This is more an inquiry into what I did wrong in my counting.  I came up with a solution of: $$\binom{3}{1} \binom{5}{3}$$  where i did C(3,1)  to account for the 3 possible places the "b" could go and C(5,3) to choose the positions of the 3 "a's"    Instead they rationalized it as $$ \binom{6}{4} (1)(1)$$

where and how did I double count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only $5$ slots for the $3$ a's if the 'b' is in the beginning. If it's in second place, there are $4$, and if it's in third place, there are $3$, so the total is

$$
\binom53+\binom43+\binom33=10+4+1=15=\binom64\;,
$$

which is the number of ways to choose $4$ out of $6$ slots for the letters "baaa" in that order.

Comment: I thought by me choosing C(3,1) I accounted for the 3 possible locations for the b

Comment: @dc3rd: You did, but then you multiplied that by a number of admissible ways of arranging the a's that actually only occurs for one of those $3$ locations of the 'b', whereas it would have to hold for all $3$ positions in order for that product to be the answer.

Comment: ah.... i see.  thank you

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see this: If the 
*b* must occur before any of the *a*'s, then our only decision is where to put the *n*'s. There are six slots available for the two *n*'s, giving ${6\choose2}=15$ possibilities. Once the *n*'s are placed we put *b,a,a,a* in the remaining open slots, in that order.